# Client side validation of L18N dates always fails for non-browser locale date formats

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a date field in asp.net mvc form which is using client side validation.
 I want it to accept dates according to the currently selected culture of the site but it always fails for anything other than the browser locale.

I don't understand what is happening here. If i specifically set up the page to use a set of l18n files then why is the validation being tested according to browser locale? How do I allow the user to override the browser locale and have input validated according their site language preference?

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
```

...

```
<div class="may-frm-edgrp">
        <label class="mfrm-lbl-r" for="TradingSince">Trading Since</label>
        <div class="may-frm-input-block">
            <input value="" class="dateTimePickerInput, mfrm-input mfrm-input-190 input-validation-error" data-date-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Trading Since must be a date." data-val-required="Trading since date is required" id="TradingSince" name="TradingSince" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" size="18" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the following scripts are being generated at the bottom of the document:

```
    <script src="/content/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/content/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="/content/globalization/globalize-master/lib/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="/content/js/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
<script src="/content/globalization/date-picker/datepicker-en-GB.js"></script>
<script src="/content/globalization/globalize-master/lib/cultures/globalize.culture.en-GB.js"></script>
```

but to no avail. How do i set this up so that it properly validates according to the en-GB override?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so the way to make this work is to override the overrides in jquery.validate.globalize.js which enhances form validation by combining the plugins

- jquery.validate.min.js and
- globalize.js.

So jquery.validate.min.js stores its magic in various css properties. 
Microsoft then provides

> jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

that uses the same base jquery.validate.min.js plugin but overrides css as the storage mechanism as instead opts for data- attributes. So

> jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

is essentially an adapter for

> jquery.validate.min.js

to use data- attributes. However the resulting validation will use the culture of the users browser defaulting to US based culture in the places where this falls short which is almost everywhere for non us users especially around currency and dates.

So to globalize our apps we can use

> globalize.js

which parses and formats according to a specific locale. We can inject these locales via any one of hundreds of available

globalize.culture.*.js

where * might be en-GB, ro-RO etc.

These files will adapt the base globalize.js plugin to work with just about any culture. 
To connect the  globalize.js plugin to the validation plugin we can override the validation methods in jquery.validate.min.js from say:

```
    date: function( value, element ) {
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value).toString());
    },
```

to :

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    var val = Globalize.parseDate(value);
    return this.optional(element) || (val instanceof Date);
};
```

as per this article

http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.co.nz/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html

This will still only default to using the browsers UI culture to do the validation but at least now forms can be validated properly on the client according to users browsers locale.

In my case I also needed to override this default as we allow the user to select the language etc to use the current site. So site language now needs preference over browser language.

So in my case even though I was supplying

> globalize.culture.en-GB.js

my forms were being validated according to en-US as that was the browser UI culture.

If i changed the browser UI culture to Romanian and supplied

> globalize.culture.ro-RO.js

then the site would properly client side validate in Romanian not en-US, but what if a user in Romania wants to read the site in English?

For that we need to allow the user to select their current culture on site. So we use a flags drop down for selection and store culture in cookie for example. Then on request inject the culture into the html tag:

```
<html lang="en-GB">
```

Then in document.OnReady{} set :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            Globalize.cultureSelector = $('html').attr('lang');
```

This will override Globalize.cultureSelector in globalize.js.

Then we need to parse in this value to the validator methods from

```
jquery.validate.globalize.js
```

to look for and supply this value to Globalize.parse:

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    var val = Globalize.parseDate(value, null, Globalize.cultureSelector);
    return this.optional(element) || (val instanceof Date);
};
```

Globalize will then use the requested culture rather than the default browser culture to parse and format values and then subsequently pass these into jquery.validate.min.js for *actual* validation.

Why do we still need to pass this value in if we have updated Globalize.cultureSelector?
Becuase if we don't the Globalize.parse method will just use the default / base culture which will always be that of the browser no matter what

globalize.culture.*.js

we have passed in. Alternatively if you dont want to do this on every page just modify the validator method to read directly form the html tag.

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    var val = Globalize.parseDate(value, null, $('html').attr('lang'));
    return this.optional(element) || (val instanceof Date);
};
```